# Hash Tables: Ice Cream Parlor solution in javascript

Tags: javascript, array, hash-map

I tried solving the [Hash Tables: Ice Cream Parlor](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-ice-cream-parlor/problem) question in javascript:

```
'use strict';

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');

let inputString = '';
let currentLine = 0;

process.stdin.on('data', inputStdin => {
    inputString += inputStdin;
});

process.stdin.on('end', function() {
    inputString = inputString.replace(/\s*$/, '')
        .split('\n')
        .map(str => str.replace(/\s*$/, ''));

    main();
});

function readLine() {
    return inputString[currentLine++];
}

// Complete the whatFlavors function below.
function whatFlavors(cost, money) {

// Solution starts here
  var dict1={};

  var len=cost.length;

  for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {

    if (cost[i]<money) {
      if(dict1[cost[i]] !== undefined)
      {
       if(Array.isArray(dict1[cost[i]]))
       {
         dict1[cost[i]].push(i);
       }
       else
       {
         dict1[cost[i]] = [dict1[cost[i]]];
         dict1[cost[i]].push(i);
       }
     }
     else
       dict1[cost[i]] = i;
    }
  }

  cost.sort(function(a,b) {return a-b});

  for(var j=0; j<len; j++){
    var left=0;
    var right=len-1;
    if(cost[j]<money){
      var ser=money-cost[j];
      while(left<right){
        var mid=Math.floor((left+right)/2);

        if(ser===cost[mid]){
          var val1=cost[j];
          var val2=cost[mid];
          break;
        }
        if(ser<cost[mid]){
          right = mid-1;
        }
        else{
          left = mid+1;
        }
      }
      if(val1 !== undefined && val2 !== undefined ){
        break;
      }
    }
  }


  var index1;
  var index2;
  if (val1===val2) {
     index1 = dict1[val1][0];
     index2 = dict1[val2][1];
  }
  else{
     index1 = dict1[val1];
     index2 = dict1[val2];
  }

  if (index2 > index1) {  
    console.log(index1+1, index2+1);
  }
  else{
    console.log(index2+1, index1+1);
  }
  // Solution ends here    
}

function main() {
    const t = parseInt(readLine(), 10);

    for (let tItr = 0; tItr < t; tItr++) {
        const money = parseInt(readLine(), 10);

        const n = parseInt(readLine(), 10);

        const cost = readLine().split(' ').map(costTemp => parseInt(costTemp, 10));

        whatFlavors(cost, money);
    }
}
```

It works for all inputs except when it is very large, for example when the input is very large for eg:
`30733 39289 
12352 19413 
448 3955 
74 75 
12316 34744 
2916 4669 
1941 6571 
2871 17443 
34132 42603 
1753 9623 
7217 8111 
3411 17665 
3190 16653 
1923 14237 
6307 22944 
10874 22052 
967 21913 
7562 7948 
11038 36319 
586 8260 
338 1426 
17083 37691 
11944 15889 
10347 13601 
643 1653 
18754 19595 
9561 22822 
22521 26308 
114 1965 
338 412 
8423 9497 
6371 33551 
1292 3705 
5634 9563 
14043 14669 
12566 39425 
1149 2638 
12664 12939 
10217 29104`
it simply throws `Wrong Answer`, is there a better way to write the same script?

Comment: The place to go to get help finding problems in your code is https://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was because of a silly mistake, in the binary search, it should be `while(left<=right)`:

```
'use strict';

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');

let inputString = '';
let currentLine = 0;

process.stdin.on('data', inputStdin => {
    inputString += inputStdin;
});

process.stdin.on('end', function() {
    inputString = inputString.replace(/\s*$/, '')
        .split('\n')
        .map(str => str.replace(/\s*$/, ''));

    main();
});

function readLine() {
    return inputString[currentLine++];
}

// Complete the whatFlavors function below.
function whatFlavors(cost, money) {
  // Solution starts here
  var dict1={};

  var len=cost.length;

  for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {

    if (cost[i]<money) {
      if(dict1[cost[i]] !== undefined)
      {
       if(Array.isArray(dict1[cost[i]]))
       {
         dict1[cost[i]].push(i);
       }
       else
       {
         dict1[cost[i]] = [dict1[cost[i]]];
         dict1[cost[i]].push(i);
       }
     }
     else
       dict1[cost[i]] = i;
    }
  }

  cost.sort(function(a,b) {return a-b});

  for(var j=0; j<len; j++){
    var left=0;
    var right=len-1;
    if(cost[j]<money){
      var ser=money-cost[j];
      while(left<=right){
        var mid=Math.floor((left+right)/2);

        if(ser===cost[mid]){
          var val1=cost[j];
          var val2=cost[mid];
          break;
        }
        if(ser<cost[mid]){
          right = mid-1;
        }
        else{
          left = mid+1;
        }
      }
      if(val1 !== undefined && val2 !== undefined ){
        break;
      }
    }
  }


  var index1;
  var index2;
  if (val1===val2) {
     index1 = dict1[val1][0];
     index2 = dict1[val2][1];
  }
  else{
     index1 = dict1[val1];
     index2 = dict1[val2];
  }

  if (index2 > index1) {  
    console.log(index1+1, index2+1);
  }
  else{
    console.log(index2+1, index1+1);
  }
  // Solution ends here
}

function main() {
    const t = parseInt(readLine(), 10);

    for (let tItr = 0; tItr < t; tItr++) {
        const money = parseInt(readLine(), 10);

        const n = parseInt(readLine(), 10);

        const cost = readLine().split(' ').map(costTemp => parseInt(costTemp, 10));

        whatFlavors(cost, money);
    }
}
```